# Блокировки в чате

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация, блокировка

Держу несколько вкладок stackoverflow открытым, среди моих меток держу ещё и окошки чата постоянно открытыми. Есть время -- почитываю, есть что сказать -- пишу.

Сегодня утром разблокировал компьютер -- а во всех чатах у меня вот такая картинка:

[image: your account has been utomatically suspended for posting inappropriate content and cannot chat for 29 minutes]

И меня это несколько напрягает тем, что я почти ничего не писал последние два дня (в выходные бывает и по сотни сообщений, а тут и десятка не набирается) и мне хочется разобраться в следующих вопросах:

1. Как я могу видеть, что меня флагнули? Можно ли видеть конкретные посты с жалобами?
2. Это вообще какие-то автоматические алгоритмы были? Скажем, проверяется, что я не употребляю слова из какого-то стоп-листа, если так -- хочу знать, какие слова там находятся. Вряд ли я узнаю что-то новое о русском языке, но не помешает. ;) Или это только кто-то из участников флагал на сообщения? Если так, то срабатывание идёт с одной же учётки за одно сообщение или нужно минимум две учётки?
3. Правильно ли я понимаю, что блок в одном чате сработает автоматически на все открытые чаты? Или даже расширительно -- на любые чаты.
4. Можно ли флагнуть за сообщение двухнедельной/пятимесячной давности или только за сегодняшние/вчерашние?
5. Наказываются ли каким-то образом ложные тревоги? Хотя бы в злостных случаях, когда делается попытка заблокировать неугодные аккаунты на эмоциях.

Вопросы эти меня интересуют потому что мы все помним недавний случай, когда бан с получаса быстро превратился в бан на год. Как-то не улыбает возможность просто так оказаться под санкциями.

Comment: Надо ещё добавить пункт: "Почему такая неудачная комбинация цветов текста и фона?". Уже где-то видел жалобу на это, но вроде как без ответа.

Comment: @alexolut, несколько раз тема про расцветку поднималась :-)

Comment: @Grundy видимо, дизайнеры дальтоники и проблемы не замечают. Типа, везде же так, что пристали?!

Comment: @alexolut, либо тема одна и так же с другими чатами, и например на enSO - нормально смотрится :)

Comment: Судя по профилю в чате, вас забанили вот за это: http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/35118472/history

Comment: @PashaPash **Модератор! При размещении ссылки, проверь её доступность рядовым участникам SO!** // это надо добавить в модераторское меню жирным текстом, и чтоб мигало :)

Comment: @alexolut, возможно автору сообщения ссылка доступна

Comment: @Grundy Доступна. Что не понравилось боту в сообщении хоть убей не пойму -- сообщение как сообщение, вполне пристойное. Разве что кому-то не понравился текст и нажал на флаг. Если так -- я ещё больше подозреваю, что можно флагать любые нормальные сообщения и за ложные тревоги никаких наказаний не будет. Плохо.

Comment: @AK да, скорее всего пришел англоязычный модер и тупо нажал "удалить".

Comment: @AK, бот флаги не обрабатывает. Он просто отслеживает сколько раз было флагнуто и сколько удовлетворено

Comment: @PashaPash надо сделать проверку "я понимаю русский язык" для таких удаляторов а-ля "я не робот".

Comment: @alexolut, http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3008/199934 . Спасибо.

Comment: Баны на год и дольше были выданы лично @NicolasChabanovsky вручную, не автоматикой, насколько мне известно.

Comment: @D-side, здесь стоило бы всем раздать, а политоту вообще прикрыть на время :)

Comment: @Grundy так и вижу: 1 марта 2017 года. StackOverflow на русском. Количество участников: 1.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не, как минимум модераторы + Nicolas + я, как единственный профессионал :-D

Comment: @Grundy а модераторы-то почему? Это хамьё в первую очередь.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, потому что они могут сами себя разбанить :-D

Comment: @Grundy если всех разом, то не успеют) Да и зачем бан если есть `DELETE FROM users` =)

Comment: Пора вводить окраску (предупреждающую) ников в чатах. Вот так, дошутились...

Answer (score 8):

> 1. Как я могу видеть, что меня флагнули? Можно ли видеть конкретные посты с жалобами?

Флагнутые сообщения видны в чатах SE, если общая репутация по ним больше 10000

> 2. Это вообще какие-то автоматические алгоритмы были?

При достаточном количестве *подтвержденных* флагов, происходит автоматическая блокировка.

> 3. Правильно ли я понимаю, что блок в одном чате сработает автоматически на все открытые чаты? Или даже расширительно -- на любые чаты.

В SE нет разделения между чатами, поэтому если заблокировали в одном чате сети, результат будет виден во всех. Исключение составляют чаты enSO, у них отдельный пользователь, отдельная репутация и все остальное тоже отделено от SE.

> 4. Можно ли флагнуть за сообщение двухнедельной/пятимесячной давности или только за сегодняшние/вчерашние?

Для флагов нет срока давности, можно флагнуть любое сообщение.

> 5. Наказываются ли каким-то образом ложные тревоги? Хотя бы в злостных случаях, когда делается попытка заблокировать неугодные аккаунты на эмоциях.

Нет ответа. Но можно предположить, что статистика ведется и в крайнем случае модераторы могут увидеть, что что-то не так.

Comment: Какое количество достаточное? Чатов 3 разных, насколько я знаю: SO, META SE, всё остальное (SE).