# Как узнать, на каких моих сообщениях или комментариях есть тревоги?

Tags: предложение, тревоги

Хочу увидеть список моих сообщений и комментариев, на которые другие участники подняли тревогу. Такое нужно для обеспечения моментальной обратной связи, чтобы я мог бы знать заранее, что моё поведение на сайте рассматривается как неприемлемое, и в скорости может последовать блокировка.

Кроме того, есть специальный случай тревог на комментариях "Более не является необходимым". Я мог бы тогда удалить свой комментарий без необходимости тревожить модератора - им меньше работы.

Желательно, чтобы эти сведения появлялись мгновенно в центре уведомлений, а не только на какой-то выделенной странице в профиле.

Comment: Хотите выполнять работу модератора? [Становитесь модератором!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1)

Comment: меня в этом плане больше интересуют только *мои* реплики..

Comment: значит будете модератором-эгоистом :)

Comment: Не дубликат, но [смежный вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4694/213987), поэтому упомяну в комментариях.

Answer (score 4):

## Если вы заслужили блокировку — вы об этом уже знаете

Или хотя бы подозреваете. Чаще всего мы блокируем участников за:

- оскорбления,
- плагиат,
- накрутку репутации с помощью дополнительных учеток.

> чтобы я мог бы знать заранее, что моё поведение на сайте рассматривается как неприемлемое, и в скорости может последовать блокировка.

Если вы делали что-то из списка выше — знайте.
Если не делали — сохраняйте спокойствие и продолжайте работу.

## Тревоги анонимны

Нельзя раскрывать даже факт того, что на сообщение поставлена тревога.
Есть риск, что автора тревоги угадают.

## Тревоги бывают ошибочными

Когда модератор видит ошибочную тревогу, он отклоняет ее.
При этом он выбирает одно из нескольких готовых сообщений или пишет своё.
После этого автор тревоги может увидеть это сообщение в истории своих тревог.

Когда ещё была тревога «неконструктивный комментарий», её постоянно ставили на вполне конструктивную критику.
Сейчас вроде бы стало реже, но всё равно случается.

Представьте: вы написали пару комментариев с конструктивной критикой ответа, а автор ответа понаставил на них тревог.
Для него ваша критика является оскорбительной, а вы сам — старожил-тиран, который выдавливает новичков.
Он требует, чтобы модераторы удалили сообщения, а вас забанили на подольше.

Что полезного вы сможете сделать с уведомлениями об этих тревогах?
Только угадать их автора.
Но у вас мало шансов его переубедить, потому что он уже в состоянии конфликта, слушать не будет.